# How to create a webpart to show exixting document library on the subsite page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, web-part

I have 10 sub sites on my company SharePoint  and each sub site has its own document library.

I'm trying to display library on web page.

Please suggest something. 
*This is the original web part that already display on the page but only for 3 subsites. Thus, I need to create 7 more web parts to display the document library on those 7 subsites.And I want the web part categories same as the existing one.
*Another is the view of document library on those previous 3 subsites.[image]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit the Page *(if a publishing site you may be prompted to check it out)*
2. Add a Web Part *(if a web part page, there will be buttons in each zone, if not then the option should be available in the ribbon)*
3. In the web part choices under Apps your document library should be listed
4. Select it and click the Add button
5. Stop editing the page *(if a publishing site, check it in then publish)*

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have 3 subsites have displayed the document library on web page so I need to make the rest of 7 to display on the page too. I have tried the method that you said, but the web part looks different as the 3 subsites when I editing the web part. Please look at the image. Thanks.

Comment: @Blue I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what you're trying to do. From your new edits, it looks like you are using a CQWP. You should be able to export the web part from one of the existing sites (edit the page, Export is in the Web Part dropdown menu on the upper-right of the wp). Then go to the new subsite, edit the page, add a web part, import your part (click upload, add again, select it). Then edit it's properties to point to that site's library instead.